# Is WSO2 API Manager support RAML specification?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

Is WSO2 API Manager support RAML specification? I want use RAML spec in the place of swagger 2.0. I am using WSO2 AM 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - WSO2 API Manager 1.9.0 doesn't support RAML. However there was a discussion on adding this support in API Manager[1].

[1] http://markmail.org/message/5noiwvohgpd2sk6q?q=Supporting+RAML+in+API+Manager

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.